# Firebase auth vs. GoogleAccountCredetial

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have an android app that can login with google account using **GoogleAccountCredential** that allows me communicate e.g. with Google Spreadsheet API.
see https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android

Now I would like to add functionality that communicate also with **Firebase Database** and I wonder if there is any way how to do it with just one sign-in method. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Which one is better? Do I need both? Does user see "google sign-in dialog" twice? Can I somehow reuse some auth-objects to other method?

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I have some apps That do this; specifically login to firebase then setup a credential to create and write to a google sheet using the api.  This code assumes you have oauth correctly setup in the android project and on the developers console.  You enable the api for sheets there as well.

once that is done get the google-services.json from the firebase console and place it in your android project.

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = 
{SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, SheetsScopes.DRIVE_FILE};

// used for spreadsheet access only
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(),Arrays.asList(SCOPES));


// set exponential backoff policy
    mCredential.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

   setCredentailAccount();


private void setCredentailAccount() {

    if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
        mCredential.setSelectedAccount(
                new 
Account(mFirebaseUser.getEmail(),getPackageName()));

        Log.i(TAG, "getAcctPermission - account set");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "getAcctPermission - account not set");
    }
}
```

I also implemented a separate login activity that incapsulates the login for the app.  There are plenty of code samples for a firebase login.  The Google credential is what is passed into the task to do the spreadsheet stuff.  Also The oauth screen on the Api console has credentials for sheets that need to be added.