# Obtaining GoogleCredentials from One Tap Signin

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Drive and let the user choose which Google account is used for the upload.

I'm following this guide:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads

As indicated, it demands some OAuth credentials to connect to the Drive API:

> ```
> // Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
> // TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity for
> // guides on implementing OAuth2 for your application.
> ```

I've managed to get a `SignInCredential` object from the One Tap client, but now I'm trying to convert it to a `GoogleCredentials` object for Google Drive API.

Using the code inside the guide

```
GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
        .createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
```

...ends up in a crash:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available.

And if I try to create the credentials on my own

```
    val accessToken = AccessToken(token, Date(0L))
    val credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.create(accessToken)
```

I also ends up in a crash:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth2Credentials instance does not
> support refreshing the access token. An instance with a new access
> token should be used, or a derived type that supports refreshing.

What are we supposed to do here?

Comment: The one tap signin is authentication or login.  It is not oauth2 authorization.  Your not going to be able to use that to get access to google drive

Comment: So what are we supposed to do instead?

Comment: @avalancha we're supposed to use OAuth2 and do stuff like this:
`val credentials: GoogleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    getApplicationContext(), Collections.singleton(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE)
                )`
I haven't been able to go all the way through though, so if you ever make it work please let me know I'm very interested!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was trying to do the exact same thing and it was quite the journey to get this working. Several separate pieces of documentation are necessary, in completely different places, sometimes disagreeing with each other, sometimes horrendously out of date, linking to deprecated or lost resources and with aged code and dependencies.

If you just want to see the code, [here you go](https://github.com/Ellie-Coding/google-one-tap-drive).

The following is my best effort to piece this together - in a minimal sample, with modern code - but I know that authentication and authorization are delicate subjects so I urge any readers to please comment any security flaws I have in this code below

## 1. Setup Google Cloud

Generally we'll be following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started) first, we'll need other links from time to time.

- Setup a project in the [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

  - For me, project type was "external"
  - Only "App name", "user support email" and "developer contact email" were mandatory. I will always mention only the bare minimum I needed to make this work
  - For the next page, "Scopes", we'll need [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth), in which you can find out which scope you need. I used `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`, make sure to match your choice to the code later on. Note that [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent) also helps with this, especially if you need to edit later
  - As a test user I added only myself. Note that all this works with unpublished and un-reviewed projects
- The tutorial recommends setting up the legal docs on the OAuth Consent screen now but it is not necessary for now
- Now follow the credential setup to the letter, create an Android Client ID (you can get the SHA-1 signature via `gradle signingReport`, **make sure to get the `debug` key, not the `debugAndroidTest` key**, and be aware that this will authenticate your **debug** app, if you want to make a release build later you will have to add another Client ID to the Google Cloud console for that one as well) and a WebClient ID

## 2. Setup the code

Now we follow [this documenation](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials) in combination with [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata) and [this](https://github.com/googleworkspace/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation)

- Add these dependencies to your app

```
implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.16.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.42.3'
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:2.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20230212-2.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

I combined One-Tap and Google Drive dependencies here. These are up-to-date at the time of writing. Don't take the versions from [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java), they are out of date and don't even compile with each other. Also we need an Android API client, not  the Java "Jetty" setup

- Setup the `oneTapClient` and the request like in the tutorial, make sure to use your WebClientId and **do not** replace hypens with em-dashes in the strings.xml as Lint recommends. Check [my Github code](https://github.com/Ellie-Coding/google-one-tap-drive/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/elliecoding/onetapdrive/MainActivity.kt) `startOneTapSignIn`-method for a more modern implementation with an ActivityResultContract instead of `startActivityForResult` handling
- Now we need a `android.accounts.Account` to be able to use the method you mentioned above, to get a `GoogleAccountCredential` (which is just a fancy `HttpRequestInitializer` which we can use later for the Drive Service).

```
val credentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, 
    Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA)
).setSelectedAccount(account)
```

- This is where I got stuck and what brought me to this question. The legacy login - which is used in all the Google drive samples - provides this out of the box via

```
GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
   .addOnSuccessListener { googleAccount: GoogleSignInAccount ->
```

- But we can solve this. [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58421822/1955202) nudged me in the right direction, we can create an account instance ourselves! After some trial and error I found out that Google requires the user email, we can find that in the `oneTapCredential.id`

```
val oneTapCredential: SignInCredential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
Log.d(TAG, "Signed in as " + oneTapCredential.displayName)
saveLoginSuccess(this, Account(oneTapCredential.id, packageName))
```

- That's it, now you can use [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata) in combination with [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java) and [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads) to setup the Google Drive Service like so

```
@WorkerThread
fun download(credentials: HttpRequestInitializer): String? {
    val service =
        Drive.Builder(
            NetHttpTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            credentials
        ).setApplicationName("OneTapDrive")
            .build()
```

For a full example of upload and download, again, see the Github

Comment: Were you able to show the Google Drive consent screen with the one-tap client? No matter what I do, it doesn't show the consent screen and my requests to google drive fail.

Comment: Yup, shows up for me. Can you install the demo app in the GitHub (don't forget to add your own Google Cloud data in config.xml) and open an issue with reproduction steps if you still have trouble?

Comment: I ended up ditching the new one tap client in favor of the supposedly deprecated OAuth client. Thanks anyways!!

Comment: @guy.gc same here. I'm also considering ditching one tap and using the old client

Comment: @avalancha what is config.xml? I never heard about this file

Comment: @ChrisB. it's a file in my Github demo project, there's some more info in the README as well

Comment: GoogleAccountCredential is deprecated. How to replace it?